# Creating a web indexer in Java?

Tags: search, indexing, web-crawler

I'm supposed to write a web crawler in Java. The crawling part is easy, but the indexing part is difficult. I need to be able to query the indexer and have it return matches (multiple word queries). What would be the best data structure for doing such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

Use an indexing tool such as [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/), [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Compass](http://compass-project.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the index & search step is to use an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) data structure, and the best available open source package that implements this for indexing & search is [Lucence](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/).

There are also open source projects that provide a composite solution to the crawling, indexing & searching steps which may be of interest, e.g. [nutch](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/)

This [free online book](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/irbook.html) on information retrieval may help you (see chapter on [constructing an inverted index](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/index-construction-1.html)).

Answer (score 0):

If you're buliding this from scratch you should look at the [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) data structure. If you can use one off the shelf then look at the [Nutch](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/) project.